# 400 Bad request for validate package

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Getting 400 bad request under following code:

The below function is used to validate the package

```
function ValidatePackage([String] $MeridiumToken, [String] $PackageName, [String] $DNSURL) {
    try {
        Write-Host "Package Validation Process Started for - $PackageName...."
        $APIVURL = $DNSURL + '/api/v1/core/metadata/import/validatemetadata'
        Write-Host $APIVURL
    

    # Encode Type
    $EncodeType = "iso-8859-1"

    # Dynamic input parameters section
    $FilePath = "$($env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/Subtract-a-thon/Automation/" + $PackageName

    # Request Headers
    $VHeaders = @{ 'MeridiumToken' = $MeridiumToken }

    # Reading Package
    # Write-Host "Reading Package..."
    $FileBinary = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
    $Enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($EncodeType)
    $FileEnc = $Enc.GetString($FileBinary)

    $CRLF = "`r`n"
    $Boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()

    # FileName
    $FileName = Split-Path $FilePath -leaf

    # Request Body
    $VBody = (
        "--$Boundary",
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"$FileName`"",
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$CRLF",
        $FileEnc,
        "--$Boundary--"
    ) -join $CRLF

    # Request Content Type
    $VContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$Boundary`""

    # REST Call
    # Write-Host "Validating Package..."
    $ValidateResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $APIVURL -Method Post -Headers $VHeaders -ContentType $VContentType -Body $VBody
    $PkgItems = $ValidateResponse | ConvertTo-Json
    Write-Host "Package Validation Process Finished for -" $PackageName
    if ($PkgItems.StartsWith("{")) {
        $PkgItems = "[$PkgItems]"
    }
    return $PkgItems
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "An error occurred:"
        Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
        throw $_
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP 400 is a generic error: without knowing the details of the API and the body you're trying to post it's impossible to give an exact indication of the error. Usually it's caused by a problem with the content (data doesn't match the content-type, incorrect charset, incorrect parameters). A lot of servers actually provide you with a detailed error message within the 400 error (so I'd advise to check the exception details in the error)

Comment: You may not have permission to access the folder SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY on the server especially if the server is a IIS.  It is better to use a network drive for storage and the server file system.  The default credential is GUEST and do not have permission to write to the server resources.

Comment: SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY this one is taking from my system actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Package count syntax due to which everything was coming blank, after correcting the Count syntax it worked